# Hive Merge Query - Error evaluating cardinality_violation(_col0,_col1)

Tags: sql, merge, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a Hive query. It fails with the following error.

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"_col0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":1},"_col1":"2020-10-28"},"value":{"_col0":1}}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"_col0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":1},"_col1":"2020-10-28"},"value":{"_col0":1}}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating cardinality_violation(_col0,_col1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.process(FilterOperator.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1022)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:827)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.process(GroupByOperator.java:767)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cardinality Violation in Merge statement: [0, -1, 1],2020-10-12
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFCardinalityViolation.evaluate(GenericUDFCardinalityViolation.java:56)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:81)
        ... 15 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Below is the query ,

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 A
using  (select * from TABLE2) B
ON
LOWER(TRIM(A.A)) = LOWER(TRIM(B.A)) AND
LOWER(TRIM(A.B)) = LOWER(TRIM(B.B))
WHEN MATCHED AND LOWER(TRIM(A.C)) = LOWER(TRIM(B.C))  OR TRIM(A.D)= TRIM(B.D)
THEN
UPDATE SET
A= regexp_replace(A,"[^ ']","#"),
B= regexp_replace(B,"[^@.]","#"),
C= regexp_replace(C,"[^.-]","#"),
D= regexp_replace(D, "[^ ']","#"),
E= regexp_replace(E, "[^ ']","#" ),
F= regexp_replace(F, "[^ .+-]","#"),
G= regexp_replace(G,"[^ ']","#"),
H= regexp_replace(H,"[^ ']","#"),
I= regexp_replace(I,"[^ ']","#"),
J= regexp_replace(J,"[^ ']","#"),
K= regexp_replace(K,"[^ ']","#"),
L= regexp_replace(L,"[^ .+-]","#"),
M= regexp_replace(M,"[^ ']","#"),
N= regexp_replace(N,"[^ ']","#"),
O= regexp_replace(O,"[^ ']","#"),
P= regexp_replace(P,"[^ ']","#"),
Q= regexp_replace(Q,"[^ ']","#"),
R= regexp_replace(R,"[^ .+-]","#"),
S= regexp_replace(S,"[^ ']","#"),
T= regexp_replace(T,"[^ +-.]","#");
```

Tried to switch of the Cardinality and it failed with arrayould of bound exception.

Please do share knowledge or insights having any information or solution.

Checked a couple of overstack and did not find any clue related to this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching of the cardinality check (`hive.merge.cardinality.check=false`) will lead to some data corruption if it will work at all.

Examine your data and fix the issue. The problem is that more than 1 row from TABLE2 matches the same row in TABLE1. It can be duplication in join key, which you can fix using `row_number` filter or `distinct`, etc, or fix your ON clause, add more keys which will make it unique.

Comment: I have cleaned the duplicates in table2. Can this issue occur because of a single row in table2 having multiple rows in Table1 ?

Comment: Thee are completely no duplicates in Table2 ( Cleaned and verified the same again ) Still the same issue is happening. There are only 4 columns in Table2 , and not more than that. Not sure if Join key is bringing duplicates. Need to check on the same.

Comment: @SamBerchmans how did you check duplicates? I guess only keys in ON condition matter

Comment: I had tried to run join Table1 and table2 and tried to get the result data to see if there is a cartesian product. There are few. Tried to enhance the key columns on the same to avoid these failures. But still no good luck. Also table2 had duplicates, which i had cleaned up manually using distinct and raw_over() functions.

Comment: @;eftjoin - I tried running the same as Update statement , it fails with the following exception. 
`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
        ... 7 more`
Looks little different. If you are aware of that also please do help.

Comment: row_number() over (partition by B.A, B.B) rn  and then filter by rn>1

Comment: This is for Table2 right ? I have manually cleared the duplicates using the same logic

Comment: It should be` row_number() over (partition by lower(trim(B.A)), lower(trim(B.B))) `

Comment: @SamBerchmans Your last exception looks like this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/getting-error-while-submitting-merge-query/td-p/208991

Comment: Do i need to use that sample you had shared in the Merge query, or should i do it separately and create a new table2? I have now created a non duplicate table like that. 
If it needs to be done with the merge, please do share a sample Query. I am not able to understand it.